# drawing a large size triangular imageview in android

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to have a triangular imageView , it works fine but it draws an imageView of little size (1 inch aprx).
even if i am giving it height ="1000px" width="700dp" it draws a little imageView
can i be guided to solve this issue, any help in appriciated.!

```
public class TriangleImageView extends ImageView {

   public TriangleImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(ctx, attrs);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

          Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

          if (drawable == null) {
                 return;
          }

          if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
                 return;
          }
          Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
          Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

          int w = getWidth();

          int h = getHeight();

          Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
          canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

   }

   public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
          Bitmap finalBitmap;
          //radius = 700;
          if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
                 finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                              false);
          else
                 finalBitmap = bitmap;
          Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                       finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

          Paint paint = new Paint();
          final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                       finalBitmap.getHeight());

          Point point1_draw = new Point(90, 0);
          Point point2_draw = new Point(0, 180);
          Point point3_draw = new Point(180, 180);

          Path path = new Path();
          path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
          path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
          path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
          path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
          path.close();
          canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
          paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
          paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
          canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

          return output;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class TriangleImageView extends ImageView {

    public TriangleImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth();

    int h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
    Bitmap finalBitmap;
    //radius = 700;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
        finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                false);
    else
        finalBitmap = bitmap;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
            finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
            finalBitmap.getHeight());

    Point point1_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth()/2, 0);
    Point point2_draw = new Point(0, finalBitmap.getHeight());
    Point point3_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight());

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me points for a hexagone shape imageview.?

Answer (score 0):

```
              Point point1_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth()/2, 0);
              Point point2_draw = new Point(0, 100);
              Point point3_draw = new Point(0, 600);
              Point point4_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth()/2, finalBitmap.getHeight());
              Point point5_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth(), 600);
              Point point6_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth(), 100);
```